# Patching of Windows Server 2012 running SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

We have patching on servers running SQL Server 2014. Good thing we have always on availability group. Bad thing, they are patching Primary Server first. Trying to understand how this is going to work.
1) Primary gets patched, DBs fail over to Secondary automatically. 
2) Assuming all goes well, Primary will come back up and becomes secondary,
   DBS get back in Sync.
3) Next day, they patch secondary (which is at this point primary) and another 
   fail over happens and roles change.

Does it sound correct?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is backwards.

Typically, you wanna patch the secondary, let that sit around for a few days, then fail over to it manually.

Once things are up and running there, run some smoke tests. If all those pass, patch the primary, and fail back during your next maintenance window.

> "Primary gets patched, DBs fail over to Secondary automatically"

You don't have a dev environment to test this stuff on, huh?

Comment: Ya, unfortunately, these guys have a very bad way of patching their servers. I fought hard to do it the way you mentioned but they will just not listen.

Comment: @jacky okay, so what's your question?